# Implementing union operation for two sets given as arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, set-operations

I need to create a union array of two sets, given as C-arrays.
This is what I have so far. I think my if condition is correct, but the output only print out one set of that array.
Can you point out what I did wrong?

```
#include "union_intersection.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <typename T>
void Union(T* left,   int left_size,
           T* right,  int right_size,
           T* result, int& result_size)
{
    
    int i=0, j=0;
    while (i< left_size && j <right_size){
        if (left < right)
        {
            result = left;
            cout<< *result<< "\t";
            i++;
            left++;
            result_size++;
        }
        else if (right<left)
        {
            result =right;
            cout<< *result << "\t";
            j++;
            right++;
            result_size++;
        }
        else
        {
           result =left;
           cout<< *result <<"\t";
           i++; j++;
           left++;
           right++;
           result_size++;
        }

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Do you mind posting a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the caller of the function `Union`?

Comment: I think the `if` conditions are wrong because comparing these pointer doesn't seem what you want to do.

Comment: This code makes no changes to the `result` array.

Comment: You might want to look at [cppreference's sample implementation of set_union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union)

Answer (score 0):

- You are comparing pointers, not what are pointed at.
- When it reaches at the end of one array, contents of the other arrays will be ignored because the condition in `while` requires that both array have some elements left.

Try this:

```
#include "union_intersection.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <typename T>
void Union(T* left, int left_size, T* right,
               int right_size, T* result, int& result_size)
{
    
    int i=0, j=0;
    while (i< left_size || j <right_size){ // change condition to "at least one array have unprocessed elements"
        if (j >= right_size || *left < *right) // compare what is pointed at, and add condition "reached at end of one array"
        {
            result = left;
            cout<< *result<< "\t";
            i++;
            left++;
            result_size++;
        }
        else if (i >= left_size || *right<*left) // compare what is pointed at, and add condition "reached at end of one array"
        {
            result =right;
            cout<< *result << "\t";
            j++;
            right++;
            result_size++;
        }
        else
        {
            result =left;
            cout<< *result <<"\t";
           i++; j++;
           left++;
           right++;
           result_size++;
        }

    }
    
}
```

Also it looks weird that the value of the argument `result` is ignored and used as simple local variable, but I don't think this is invalid because the question only says about printing out and there are no specifications about what should be written or read to/from what is pointed at by `result`.

Answer (score 0):

With @MikeCat help, below is my finish function.
I also include the loop to print out the remaining element.

```
template <typename T>
void Union(T* left, int left_size, T* right,
               int right_size, T* result, int& result_size)
{

    int i=0, j=0;
    while (i< left_size && j <right_size){
        if (*left < *right || j >=right_size)
        {
            result = left;
            cout<< *result<< "\t";
            i++;
            left++;
            result_size++;
        }
        else if (*right<*left || i>= left_size)
        {
            result =right;
            cout<< *result << "\t";
            j++;
            right++;
            result_size++;
        }
        else
        {
            result =left;
            cout<< *result <<"\t";
           i++; j++;
           left++;
           right++;
           result_size++;
        }

    }
    while (i < left_size)
    {
        cout<< *left<< "\t";
        left++;
        ++i;
        result_size++;
    }
    while (j < right_size)
    {
        cout<< *right<< "\t";
        ++j;
        right++;
        result_size++;
    }

}
```